# Does my singing sound fluent?

Tags: traducción, gramática, selección-de-palabras, pronunciación

---

***UPDATE AGAIN: i'm singing [this other song](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/singing-deje-de-amar-slowed-down/s-K4Ko0Zxcc1M?si=bc49787fe6ec460ea1640c0fc39e4db3) to practice. any advice would be appreciated!!!***

EDIT: i just realized, i was erroneously attempting to roll the R's that followed "t" and "c" in  "cruzados" and "encontró". i'll stop doing that

---

previous update: Here are my latest attempts after taking Ángel José Riesgo's advice:

[newer audio sample](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/revised-attempts/s-NXMZy2ePm52?si=75159fc8af1d49e097d36e9e7a2799b4)

I can tell I'm not quite there yet, at least not consistently. Which T's and D's here sound the best -- and do any other phonemes need work?

---

This is the last line of a song I wrote:

> Soñaba con una fidelidad como la tuya.

(OUTDATED, SEE ABOVE): [soñaba con una fidelidad como la tuya](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/sonaba-con-una-fidelidad-como-la-tuya/s-whjxBC2m5GH?si=f7e56e90377c4ee688bbceac6658d728)

My intended meaning is "I always dreamed of a faith like yours." The song's tone is meant to be formal, self-serious, grandiose.

1. Is the line grammatically correct?
2. Would a fluent speaker phrase it that way?
3. Does its cadence flow well with the melody?
4. How's my enunciation and delivery?

Here are two more (OUTDATED) samples: "don't cry if not for me. [ve a dormir ahora](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/dont-cry-if-not-for-me-ve-a-dormir-ahora/s-ihL9HAyQ5wI?si=7e8f40420a2244c595f42367bdf1366e) (go to sleep now)." "please be faithful while i'm gone./ [guarda tus cuatro dulces patas](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/guarda-tus-cuatro-dulces-patas/s-8cQERvbamsH?si=0023adafcce54641af85a7e6fa15cfd8) (save your four sweet paws for me)." I hope this helps you judge my rolled R's and general authenticity.

I know this is asking a lot, but if there are grammar/meaning issues, I would greatly appreciate fixes that still adhere to the piano melodies at the end of each file.

Besides that, I am looking for ways I could improve to sound as authentic as possible. I record in two weeks.

Thank you!

EDIT: I just thought of something that would really help -- recommendations for songs IN spanish, at a similar tempo, whose singers have a similar voice type as mine. So I could study those songs trying to mimic them line by line.

Comment: Your accent is a little off. I can easily tell you aren't a native speaker.

Comment: @Nameless I tried again after taking Ángel's advice. Are [these attempts](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/revised-attempts/s-NXMZy2ePm52?si=75159fc8af1d49e097d36e9e7a2799b4) any better? I have two weeks to improve, I think I can get this with the right pointers.

Comment: Your pronunciation is much better, yes. However, at first, I couldn't clearly hear 'guardar'. Also, stress a bit more 'dul' in '**dul**ces'.

Comment: save your four sweet paws for me? What does that mean? Because in English: Save x for me can be taken very romantically....

Comment: The ra in  ahora sounds English, also. See this video for the /r/ and two r sounds. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8agG2fYbiPY

Comment: @Nameless That was really validating to hear, and I improved a lot from the confidence boost your message gave me alone! I'll definitely keep those tips in mind, thanks. RE-rerecording soon!

Comment: @Lambie yeah, my friend told me "guardar" was more like "protect." Does the romantic connotation not transfer? If not, I need a more fitting construction... it works in the context of the full song, you're just gonna have to trust me on that, LOL!

Thank you, too, for the resource--I've built a playlist I'm watching and reciting every day until deadline; I'll add this one to it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer your questions 1, 2 and 4 for your first audio sample (question 3 is more about music than language).

The sentence is grammatically correct, yes.

In terms of how a native speaker would say it, 'soñaba' is closer to 'I was dreaming'. 'I always dreamed of' would be 'siempre soñé/he soñado con'.

As for your pronunciation, there are two words that sound markedly foreign: 'fidelidad' and 'tuya'. This is because you pronounce the consonants 'd' and 't' as in English, which sound weird to the Spanish ear. In English, the 'd' sound is pronounced with a sudden burst of air (a 'plosive consonant' in phoneticians' terms), but in Spanish it is (mostly) pronounced with a gradual flow of air, more like the English 'th' in 'they'. So, you should try to say something like 'fee - thelly - thahth'  (/fiðeli'ðað/) to get closer to the Spanish way of saying it.

The 't' consonant in English, on the other hand, is pronounced with a noticeable puff of air ('aspiration') at the onset, which is lacking in Spanish. The Spanish 't' is a plosive, but unaspirated, consonant, articulated very similarly to the English 'd'. So, if you say 'dooya' for 'tuya' (and then try to make it a bit like 't' to make it voiceless), you will get it more similar to what a Spanish speaker would say.

Note that these remarks for the d/t pair of consonants also apply to two other pairs: b/p and g/k, but the difference is a tad less noticeable for Spanish speakers in those cases.

Comment: Thank you. This seriously opened my ears. I was especially grateful for your inclusion of the technical terms "voiceless" and "unaspirated", which helped me do some more research. I [tried again](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/revised-attempts/s-NXMZy2ePm52?si=75159fc8af1d49e097d36e9e7a2799b4)!  I can hear I'm kind of all over the place, but I'm not sure which ones sound better and which sound worse. (If there's any other problem lower on the triage list, I'd love to hear it as well.) Thanks again, Ángel!

Comment: @tbt2345 For people who are not linguists, the easiest way to explain how to make certain Spanish consonant sounds is to tell them: Stop the flow of air (aspiration) when using consonants like the c and s in casa. Or the d in moneda.

Comment: @Lambie I've been rehearsing so much, those light T's, C's, B's, and D's have started to enter my casual conversation LOL! Can't wait to rerecord so you can hear my progress. I'll certainly focus more on R's, too, now that you mentioned it.

Comment: @tbt2345 You do get the casa thing, right? Americans let out a whole bunch of air after the c and s, which is what causes the accents.

Comment: @Lambie [You be the judge!](https://soundcloud.com/tbt12345/singing-deje-de-amar-slowed-down/s-K4Ko0Zxcc1M?si=bc49787fe6ec460ea1640c0fc39e4db3) The R's are still feel a little awkward for me, but at least I'm distinguishing between the two kinds. Thanks again for all the help. Please let me know if anything else is sticking out as weird -- though I realize beyond a certain threshold my off-ness may stop being definable.

Comment: @tbt2345 Much. much better. The d in olvidarte is a little over aspirated. And: incitarón al amor, not a el. :) One minor thing, you sing about her in the third person then say tu. Perhaps su would be better since it is indirect speech.

Comment: Have you tried running your speech through one of the software packages that can rate your sound?  Some of them are pretty good,  and the constant correction will yield improvement that our comments will not.

Answer (score 1):

I would use *fidelidad* for "faithfulness".  I would use *Fé* for "faith".